# Getting nearby address from current location

Tags: php, google-maps, dictionary, google-api

Is there any way (API or library) that I get the nearby addresses (plot#, street#, city) of my locations through google map.

I am developing a neighbor app, in which I have to give access to all user that he can see his nearby neighbors addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you check out the Google Maps API here https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/maps/. Not only will that let you work with the Google Map that you want to show in your application, but it contains many features such as what you are looking for, through using things like Geocoding and what not, as well as nearby searches.